# "Descent" vs. "descend" in the context

Tags: grammaticality, word-choice

> What causes a nose bleed during **the descent**?

I am not sure that the descent is correct here or not grammatically. If it is correct so what about **descend**, **(the)descending**? Please add the reason of choice.

It is necessary to say descent/descend is the correct choice semantically to describe the job of going down into the sea from the surface during the diving. My doubts are grammatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*During* is a preposition and requires a noun or noun phrase for its object.

*Descent* is a noun and may be used as the object of a preposition.

> What causes a nose bleed during (the)<sup>†</sup> **descent**?

*Descend* is a verb—specifically, a *bare infinitive*. A bare infinitive can**not** be used as a noun. A *marked infinitive* like *to descend* may be used as a noun in some circumstances<sup>‡</sup>, but **not** as the object of a preposition—perhaps because it already has what *looks* and *sounds* like a preposition in front of it.

> <sup>**✲**</sup>What causes a nose bleed during **descend**?
>   <sup>**✲**</sup>What causes a nose bleed during **to descend**?

*Descending* is also a verb—specifically, a *gerund*. This is a form which can be used as a noun. However, *during* is not usually employed with gerunds, probably because the two consecutive *-ing*s may be confusing. Instead, we use *while*:

> What causes a nose bleed **while descending**?

---

<sup>†</sup>*The* is used only if you are speaking of a specific descent, not of descents in general.
<sup>✲</sup> *marks an utterance as unacceptable*
<sup>‡</sup>Specifically, as a verb complement, or as the head of a complementary clause:

- **To err** is human.
- I love **to run**.

Answer (score 2):

OED says of *descend* used as a ***noun*** that it's *obsolete, rare*, so we'll forget that one (most native speakers wouldn't even accept it as remotely credible today).

So the choice is between gerund *descending* and the "dedicated" noun form *descent*. And idiomatically the overwhelming preference would be for *descent* in OP's context.

I'm not sure if it's a universal rule, but it seems to me that where there's a specific noun form available, native speakers would tend to use that, rather than use a "derived" gerund.

But where the relevant verb is also commonly used as a noun anyway (for example, *walk*) we probably tend to use that rather than the gerund...

> *Ill-fitting shoes may cause blisters during a walk*. (perhaps *when walking*, but not *during [the] walking*)